# Is there a way to reference a footnote using \cite or similar command?

Tags: citing, footnotes

The formatting of the article I am writing uses the same notation to cite references and footnotes (they both appear in brackets, i.e. [1-3]).  I want to have a combined citation for both a reference and a footnote. The way I am trying right now generates two separate citations at the end of the sentence, for example:

```
\documentclass[reprint, superscriptaddress, amsmath, amssymb, aps, article]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

Here is a nice sentence \footnote{A good point}\cite{ref1}.

\end{document}
```

becomes:

> Here is a nice sentence [1][2].

while I would like it to look like:

> Here is a nice sentence [1,2].

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried looking at other postings on the forum, but I could only find information on how to add citations internally to a footnote. I think I could probably force it to work by adding a bibtex item with my desired footnote, but that will make it very hard for me to get an accurate word count (references do not count, while footnotes do). It also just seems a bit inelegant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm doubtful this is possible. The compressed number format itself only works for a single `\cite` command i.e., even `\cite{foo}\cite{bar}` will not yield [1, 2], only `\cite{foo,bar}` will.  So `\footnote{foo}\cite{bar}` is really no different.

Comment: I was hopeful there was some way to say label the footnote, but suppress its native marker and then feed it into `\cite{ref1, footnotelabel}` or some trick like that. I am still very new to latex though and I am not really sure how `\cite{}` function works or if it is that flexible.

Comment: Apparently you can! If you put the footnotes in a `.bib` file.  See [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/2693) (The second answer more relevant to you, I think.)

Comment: I would ideally like to keep the footnote separate from the references as they are treated differently by the journal (one counts towards the word limit and the other doesn't), however that seems like it is asking for too much so I will do this for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also (for the benefit of anyone else trying this) if you have to do multiple of these you can append text to the citation of a blank bibtex item as another work around.  i.e. with a bib entry of: `\article{blankref,
journal = {},
}`
you can use: `\cite{ref1, [{footnote text here}] blankref}` and it will appear in the references just like a footnote (do not add a period to your footnote text though). At least then you can edit the text in the main latex file. It still is not counted with texcount though.