# How to have footnotes nested within footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to create nested footnotes, along the lines of Infinite Jest (only with footnotes rather than endnotes). I've read the [Footnoteception](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35223/footception-footnote-within-a-footnote-within-a-footnote) post and found the Bigfoot package, which seems to have the behavior I want, i.e.,

[image: bigfoot]

In particular, footnote 2 is exactly what I want.

The problem is that I've been using the normal \footnote quite a bit throughout the text, but bigfoot doesn't follow the established footnote numbering. What should I do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using:

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
```

This is how to 'access' the normal footnotes with `bigfoot`.  For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot,lipsum}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\begin{document}

\footnote{This is the default level%
  \footnoteA{And this is the A-level.}}%
\lipsum[1]

\footnote{This is the default level%
  \footnoteA{And this is the A-level.}}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks jon! What does the \DeclareNewFootnote{default} do? The bigfoot documentation is pretty difficult to parse.

Comment: @Adam -- I know what you mean.  `bigfoot` seems set up with the assumption that you might not want to hook into the default footnote layer, so you need to specify that you do.  I think it's just a design decision....

Comment: Do you know of any other way to get the nested footnotes? I don't like how bigfoot changes the way that normal footnotes are handled (e.g., by making them double spaced). I'd like to keep TeX's default footnote usage and just augment it with nested footnotes.

Comment: @Adam -- No, I'm sorry.  (Do you mean the gap between the different types of footnote?)  `bigfoot` is based on `manyfoot`, so that might be an option....