# Footnotes and subfootnotes in plain TeX

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, plain-tex, german

I've set myself a masochistic project: I'm trying to typeset (and then translate) Martin Wolf's 1906 doctoral dissertation ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ipKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1), [HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b2635535)) in plain TeX. (I chose plain TeX because I don't want to require a lot of dependencies. I do understand that that's probably making my life more difficult than it needs to be.)

Exactly one page of the document features both footnotes and subfootnotes (that is, footnotes *to* one of the footnotes); see image at the end of this post.

I think I'm asking for more or less exactly one of the things that Bigfootnote can do, as seen in e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207743/how-to-have-footnotes-nested-within-footnotes); but in plain TeX instead of LaTeX.

Right now I've got this skeleton (this is a complete file, compilable with `pdftex test.tex`) — but I don't know what to put in the `TODO FIXME` part. The other `TODO` lines are also open questions I need to solve, but aren't related to *this* TeX.SE question.

```
\input plain-utf8.tex % https://dmitripavlov.org/tex/plain-utf8.tex

\font\footnotesize=cmr8 % TODO why doesn't this do anything

\def\pfn#1#2{\footnote{#1}{#2})} % TODO why is the number not superscripted
\def\subpfn#1#2{\pfn{#1}{#2}} % TODO FIXME everything about this
\def\glqq{\smash{\raise-1.1ex\hbox{''}}}
\def\grqq{\hbox{``}}
\def\quoted{\glqq\aftergroup\grqq}
\def\itquoted{\it\glqq\aftergroup\grqq}
\def\emph{\rm} % TODO this should letterspace
\def\vvbar{$\|$\ }

\def\footnotetextpiiiniii{
1. {\emph Segundo} \vvbar {\emph Tomo Del} \vvbar
{\emph Ingenioso Hidalgo} \vvbar {\emph Don Quixote
de la Mancha,} \vvbar que contiene su tercera salida: y es la \vvbar
quinta parte de sus aventuras.\ \vvbar Compuesto por el Licenciado Alonso Fernandez
\vvbar de~Avellaneda,
natural de la Villa de Tordesillas.\ \vvbar Al Alcalde, Regidores, y hidalgos, de la
noble villa del~(!) Argamesilla, patria feliz del hidalgo Cauallero Don Quixote \vvbar
de la Mancha.\ \vvbar (Grabadito: Caballero embistiendo lanza en
ristre\subpfn{1}{--- {\it D.~Q.} Valencia,~1605.}) \vvbar Con
Licencia. En Tarragona, en casa de Felipe \vvbar Roberto,
Año~1614.\subpfn{2}{War mir nicht zugänglich. cf.~Leopoldo Rius, a.~a.~O.~II, S.~255.}

Die Aprobacion des Doctor Raphael Orthoneda ist datiert auf den 18.~April
1614, die Druck- und Verkaufserlaubnis für das Erzbistum Tarragona auf den
4.~Juli 1614.

Es folgt eine Dedikation: al Alcade, Regidores etc.

Vorrede Avellanedas.

Sonett von Pero Fernandez.

Avellaneda teilt nach dem Muster des ersten Teiles ein und zählt weiter:
{\it quinta, sexta} und {\it septima parte,} während Cervantes seinen zweiten Teil
schlechtweg {\it Segunda Parte} nennt und weiter keine Unterabteilungen macht.

2. {\emph Vida y hechos} \vvbar {\emph del Ingenioso Hidalgo} \vvbar {\emph Don Quixote} \vvbar
{\emph de la Mancha}, \vvbar que contiene su quarta~(!) salida, \vvbar
y es la quinta parte de sus
aventuras. \vvbar Compuesto por el Licenciado Alonso Fernandez \vvbar de Avellaneda,
natural de la villa de Tordesillas.\ \vvbar Parte~II.\ Tomo~III.\ \vvbar
nuevamente añadido, y corregido en esta \vvbar Impresion, por el Licenciado
Don Isidro Perales y Torres\subpfn{3}{Nach
D.~Juan de~Iriarte {\it (Adiciones á la Bibl. esp. de Nic. Antonio)} ---
Blas Antonio Nasarre y Ferriz (1689--1751).}. \vvbar
Dedicada al Alcalde etc.\ \vvbar Año 1732 (Der Holzschnitt, der das Abenteuer mit
dem Ritter vom {\quoted hellen Mond} darstellt, findet sich schon in der Ausgabe des
{\it D.~Q.}\ Madrid,~1730)\ \vvbar Con Privilegio \vvbar En Madrid etc.

Der Titel {\it Vida y hechos} ist seit der Brüsseler Ausgabe des {\it D.~Q.}\ (1662
und~1671) gebräuchlich. Die Avellanedaausgabe sollte als Fortsetzung für die
Madrider {\it Don Quijote}-Ausgabe von~1730 gelten. Die Aprobacion von Don Agustin
de Montiano y Luyando ist sehr günstig für Avellaneda.
}

Zeit Lesages\pfn{1}{cf.~Vorrede zu seiner Übersetzung; die dort erwähnte Legende,
dass die Freunde des Cervantes alle erreichbaren Exemplare des falschen {\it Don Quijote}
verbrannt hätten, scheint mir auf {\it D.~Q.}~II,~70 zu beruhen. (Altisidoras Traum:
die Teufelchen spielen mit Avellanedas {\it Don Quijote} Ball und werfen ihn dann
in den Abgrund der Hölle.)} schon äusserst selten war. Es ist mir daher
unbegreiflich, wie Puisbusque\pfn{2}{{\it Histoire
comparée des littératures française et espagnole,} 1843, Bd.~I, S.~29.}
fragen kann: {\itquoted Pourquoi la prétendue suite
d'Avellaneda, bien que remplie d'invectives contre l'auteur, a eu plus
de succès que l'ouvrage même?}

Im ganzen sind sechs {\emph Ausgaben in spanischer Sprache}
erschienen.\pfn{3}{\footnotetextpiiiniii}

\end
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

But what I want is more like this screenshot of Wolf's original typesetting:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure what layout you wanted also I just commented out the plain-utf8 as it didn't seem to be needed in this example. As it's plain and everything is numbered by hand anyway I didn;t try to automate too much, just leave a marker in place and define a command to use in vertical mode outside the outer footnote

[image]

```
%\input plain-utf8.tex % https://dmitripavlov.org/tex/plain-utf8.tex

\font\footnotesize=cmr8 % TODO why doesn't this do anything

\def\pfn#1#2{\footnote{$^{#1}$}{#2})} % TODO why is the number not superscripted
\def\subpfn#1#2{%
  $^{#1}$\long\expandafter\gdef\csname temp#1\endcsname{%
    \vfootnote{$^{#1}$}{#2}}} % TODO FIXME everything about this
\def\glqq{\smash{\raise-1.1ex\hbox{''}}}
\def\grqq{\hbox{``}}
\def\quoted{\glqq\aftergroup\grqq}
\def\itquoted{\it\glqq\aftergroup\grqq}
\def\emph{\rm} % TODO this should letterspace
\def\vvbar{$\|$\ }

\def\footnotetextpiiiniii{
1. {\emph Segundo} \vvbar {\emph Tomo Del} \vvbar
{\emph Ingenioso Hidalgo} \vvbar {\emph Don Quixote
de la Mancha,} \vvbar que contiene su tercera salida: y es la \vvbar
quinta parte de sus aventuras.\ \vvbar Compuesto por el Licenciado Alonso Fernandez
\vvbar de~Avellaneda,
natural de la Villa de Tordesillas.\ \vvbar Al Alcalde, Regidores, y hidalgos, de la
noble villa del~(!) Argamesilla, patria feliz del hidalgo Cauallero Don Quixote \vvbar
de la Mancha.\ \vvbar (Grabadito: Caballero embistiendo lanza en
ristre\subpfn{3.1}{--- {\it D.~Q.} Valencia,~1605.}) \vvbar Con
Licencia. En Tarragona, en casa de Felipe \vvbar Roberto,
Año~1614.\subpfn{3.2}{War mir nicht zugänglich. cf.~Leopoldo Rius, a.~a.~O.~II, S.~255.}

Die Aprobacion des Doctor Raphael Orthoneda ist datiert auf den 18.~April
1614, die Druck- und Verkaufserlaubnis für das Erzbistum Tarragona auf den
4.~Juli 1614.

Es folgt eine Dedikation: al Alcade, Regidores etc.

Vorrede Avellanedas.

Sonett von Pero Fernandez.

Avellaneda teilt nach dem Muster des ersten Teiles ein und zählt weiter:
{\it quinta, sexta} und {\it septima parte,} während Cervantes seinen zweiten Teil
schlechtweg {\it Segunda Parte} nennt und weiter keine Unterabteilungen macht.

2. {\emph Vida y hechos} \vvbar {\emph del Ingenioso Hidalgo} \vvbar {\emph Don Quixote} \vvbar
{\emph de la Mancha}, \vvbar que contiene su quarta~(!) salida, \vvbar
y es la quinta parte de sus
aventuras. \vvbar Compuesto por el Licenciado Alonso Fernandez \vvbar de Avellaneda,
natural de la villa de Tordesillas.\ \vvbar Parte~II.\ Tomo~III.\ \vvbar
nuevamente añadido, y corregido en esta \vvbar Impresion, por el Licenciado
Don Isidro Perales y Torres\subpfn{3.3}{Nach
D.~Juan de~Iriarte {\it (Adiciones á la Bibl. esp. de Nic. Antonio)} ---
Blas Antonio Nasarre y Ferriz (1689--1751).}. \vvbar
Dedicada al Alcalde etc.\ \vvbar Año 1732 (Der Holzschnitt, der das Abenteuer mit
dem Ritter vom {\quoted hellen Mond} darstellt, findet sich schon in der Ausgabe des
{\it D.~Q.}\ Madrid,~1730)\ \vvbar Con Privilegio \vvbar En Madrid etc.

Der Titel {\it Vida y hechos} ist seit der Brüsseler Ausgabe des {\it D.~Q.}\ (1662
und~1671) gebräuchlich. Die Avellanedaausgabe sollte als Fortsetzung für die
Madrider {\it Don Quijote}-Ausgabe von~1730 gelten. Die Aprobacion von Don Agustin
de Montiano y Luyando ist sehr günstig für Avellaneda.
}

Zeit Lesages\pfn{1}{cf.~Vorrede zu seiner Übersetzung; die dort erwähnte Legende,
dass die Freunde des Cervantes alle erreichbaren Exemplare des falschen {\it Don Quijote}
verbrannt hätten, scheint mir auf {\it D.~Q.}~II,~70 zu beruhen. (Altisidoras Traum:
die Teufelchen spielen mit Avellanedas {\it Don Quijote} Ball und werfen ihn dann
in den Abgrund der Hölle.)} schon äusserst selten war. Es ist mir daher
unbegreiflich, wie Puisbusque\pfn{2}{{\it Histoire
comparée des littératures française et espagnole,} 1843, Bd.~I, S.~29.}
fragen kann: {\itquoted Pourquoi la prétendue suite
d'Avellaneda, bien que remplie d'invectives contre l'auteur, a eu plus
de succès que l'ouvrage même?}

Im ganzen sind sechs {\emph Ausgaben in spanischer Sprache}
erschienen.\pfn{3}{\footnotetextpiiiniii}

\csname temp3.1\endcsname
\csname temp3.2\endcsname
\csname temp3.3\endcsname
\end
```

or with smaller footnotes, add this

```
\catcode`\@=11
\def\vfootnote#1{\insert\footins\bgroup
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\ht\strutbox % top baseline for broken footnotes
  \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty\@MM
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \spaceskip\z@skip \xspaceskip\z@skip
  \footnotesize\baselineskip=10pt%%%%%%%%%%%<<<<<<<<<<<ADDED
  \textindent{#1}\footstrut\futurelet\next\fo@t}
\catcode`\@=12
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! `plain-utf8` is needed in order to keep e.g. "Übersetzung" from turning into "bersetzung" in the first line of footnote 1. For the superscripting: Thank you! Now I don't have to ask that question. :) In general, is "just drop into math mode" really the most kosher solution for superscripting text in plain TeX?

Comment: Also, how would I make the footnotes smaller than the body, and the subfootnotes smaller than the footnotes, as in the image of Wolf's original?

Comment: @Quuxplusone plain tex isn't really suitable for document production at all, it's just "basic macros" as an illustrative example for the texbook so you just have to do whatever has to be done. you can of course use `\def\textsuperscript#1{$^{#1}$}` if you'd rather hide the explicit math mode (that was for many years the latex definition of textsuperscript) and it would give you flexibility to use say `\raise\hbox{...} by 1ex` or whatever if you later decided to change.

Comment: "is needed in order to keep e.g. "Übersetzung" from turning into "bersetzung" in the first line of footnote" @Quuxplusone yes sure: utf-8 support matters to you in your real document but here for this question it's just filler text anyway and the odd accented letter disappearing doesn't matter, I am English after all, we don't do accents:-)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I added an update with smaller footnote text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle “I am English after all, we don’t do accents.”  Such naïveté!

Comment: And if the English don’t do accents, how do you explain Peter Sellars?

Comment: @DonHosek Well `ï` is a diaeresis, not an accent, and if you spell with an accent, it's a foreign word so should be in italics ;)

Comment: @JosephWright but `é` is very much an accent (and my dictionary lists naïveté as an English spelling of the word alongside naivete) and if you’re being pedantic about accent vs diacritical than David’s original comment about Übersetzung is also a target.

Comment: And as an aside, as a too-clever-by-far undergrad in the 80s, I used to go out of my way to use the word naïve in my papers, or refer to the Thomas à Kempis to show off the fact that I could type words diacriticals in them in an era in which they were largely inaccessible to most writers.

Comment: @DonHosek Sure, it was just a bit of fun with the usual 'there are no accents in English' line. [Diacritics, yes, so `ï` I'm fine with :)]

Comment: @DonHosek afortunadamente, las cosas han mejorado con los anos... :)