# Mixing footcite with numerical citation style

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use `\footcite` primarily when citing, but every now and then I want to refer to a reference as part of a sentence. These in-text references would ideally be formatted like `Ref. [2,4-6,8]`, i.e. refer to an index in the numbered bibliography. (Please see below if reading this did not make much sense.)

Also, in the same way, I want to be able to do both in-text citations and footnote citations within footnotes; the latter then would then just create a new, subsequent footnote.

Currently, what I have is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=verbose,
    bibstyle=verbose,
    sorting=nyvt,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    maxcitenames=10,
    maxbibnames=100
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\AdaptNoteOpt{\footcite}{\multfootcite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{A,
  author    = {Alpha, Amber},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year      = {2014},
}
@article{B,
  author    = {Beta, Bryan},
  title     = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  year      = {2015},
}
@article{G,
  author    = {Gamma, Gina},
  title     = {Title3},
  publisher = {Publisher3},
  year      = {2016},
}
@article{D,
  author    = {Delta, Daniel},
  title     = {Title4},
  publisher = {Publisher4},
  year      = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
While some\footcite{A}\footcite{B} argue X, Ref. \textcite{G} argues Y.%
\footnote{However, Z\footcite{D}\footcite{A} is has to be considered as an alternative,
even though Ref. \textcite{B}\textcite{G} dismiss this possibility.%
\footnote{A nested footnote.}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result I get is this:

[image: result]

Not only do the citations not work the way I intended, but also the nested citation is not showing up. While footnotes-in-footnotes may be a bit off-topic, I hope the solution does not exhibit the same problem for footcites-in-footnotes.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

[image: desired]

I'm using LuaLaTex with TeX Live 2013, in the way it comes with Ubuntu 14.04.

I'd very much appreciate any hints. I'm rather new to LaTeX and BibLaTeX in particular, so I hope this is not something I overlooked when reading the documentation. Also, please let me know in case my question is unclear.

Comment: See [Footnote to a footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23157/35864) and [Footception: Footnote within a footnote within a footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35223/35864). What In seem to take away from this is that you can never have `\footnote{lorem \footnote{ipsum}}`. For the inner footnote you would need a new `\footnoteA` (or some `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` combination). For `biblatex` this could be automated.

Comment: Let me know if you are interested in a solution that allows you to use two footnote levels with different counters and footnote marks (`\footnote` with arabic numbers and `\footnoteA` which can be nested inside a `\footnote` with alphabetic counters).

Comment: @moewe: I'd be very thankful if you could explain how your proposed solution works, even if it does not fulfill all criteria! Thank you for the offer!

Comment: @moewe: I don't want to be pushy, but here's a reminder that I'd still be interested in your suggestion, if you could find the time to write it down. Thanks!

Comment: @moewe: I'd still be happy if you could quickly write up a quick (partial) solution. Thanks!

Comment: I will think about it, ... it is going to be horrible though and really not worth the hassle.