# Can Tex make a footnote to the footnote of a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I know how to make a footnote to a footnote with package bigfoot.  Is it possible to make a third layer of footnotes, namely a footnote to the footnote of a footnote?
I am not kidding.  I do need this to make a report of the study of ancient literature.

Thanks!

Comment: Coming from a field where footnotes are sparse, I would love to see what the use case for three levels of them is. And I'm amazed that it's so easy to do with TeX.

Comment: Many people (not me) dislike even texts with single levels of footnotes. Think twice if another  layout could be better, for instance, with `linguex` or    `gb4e`. There are more [sup­port for lin­guis­tics in CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/linguistic).

Comment: @Fran: Tell me you've never seen a footnote bigger than a page.

Comment: @RobinEkman I've never used one, but it's not uncommon, for instance, to see in a footnote a large body of text that is cited.  That means the footnote itself gets blockquote text, and within that it's pretty easy to see how it could end up with the need for a footnote.  I've thankfully managed with just bracketing comments, but now that I know I can do it.... }:-)

Comment: @Joshua ...Yes I saw it, as well as a Komodo dragon longer than a 
a basketball player,  and a tapeworm longer than two humans... and some others monstrosities.

Comment: See footception: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35223/footception-footnote-within-a-footnote-within-a-footnote

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, you can create as many footnote levels as you like, as shown in the example below. You can also create a `footnoteD` from within `footnoteB`, but watch out, this can screw up the sorting of the footnotes quite badly. So please, think of your poor reader and don't skip levels, and keep the footnote'ception to a minimum.

PS: the `%` at the end of each line is to prevent LaTeX from adding a space between the end of the text and the footnote symbol

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{C}[Alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{D}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote{E}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote{F}[fnsymbol]

\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteD}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}

\begin{document}

Just some normal text\footnoteA{with footnotes!} and even more text
\footnoteA{This is a nice footnote.%
    \footnoteB{Another footnote.%
        \footnoteC{Even one more footnote.%
            \footnoteD{Omg, when does this end?%
                \footnoteE{Please stop!%
                    \footnoteF{Ok, fine... Just this last one!}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Just put a `%` at the end of the lines, and you'll avoid the spaces in the output.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for the hint - would have expected that I need to remove the indention as well. Definitely nicer that way, thank you!

Comment: No, spaces at the beginning of lines are stripped, I believe.

Comment: @hbaderts The `%` makes all text until the end of the line a comment *and* strips the leading whitespace in the following line.

Comment: You should put a footnote to itself at the end: infinite footnotation.

Comment: @coredump that would be fun, but you can only create footnotes in lower hierarchies - which of course makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @hbaderts You can cheat. For example, with the default footnote: `Recursion\footnote{See also: recursion\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotemark{}}`.