# Showing url on footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

Sometimes, I want to display all `\href` content on my document, so I defined:

```
\ifdefined\isprintable
  \usepackage{manyfoot}
  \DeclareNewFootnote{URL}[roman]
  \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnoteURL{\url{#1}}}
\fi
```

So, I only have to put \isprintable on the preamble to got this behaviour.

But, I have some `\href` commands included on `\footnote`.

As I see on [a stack tread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/footnote-to-a-footnote) and [the TUG mailing list](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2010-April/014842.html), it is impossible to put a footnote on another one, unless we do `\footnote{This is the principal footnote\footnotemark{}.}\footnotetext{This is the second one.}` witch imply to separate the command witch mark the place of the footnote from the command woh define the text of the footnote. But, we can’t do this with `href`.

There is not an `\hrefmark` and a `\hreftext`.

So witch solution I still have to display all urls of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `bigfoot` allows you to have several layers of footnotes, and footnotes of a higher level can have footnotes on a lower layer.

In this example we have "normal" footnotes numbered in Arabic and `href` footnotes numbered in roman:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{1in} % For demonstration we want a short page 
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}    % standard footnotes  
\DeclareNewFootnote{URL}[roman] % href footnotes
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnoteURL{\url{#1}}}
\begin{document}
You can find many answers on
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{stackexchange}.  Some questions
can be really complex\footnote{For example,
  \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236424/showing-url-on-footnote}{this
    question}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It work fine. `bigfoot` is the package I was searching.