# Glossary footnote in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I use glossaries-extra.
I write a report containing several acronyms and definitions. And the first time I use it, I display the definition of in the footnote.
But I have a regular case of an acronym referring to a definition, and vice versa like here :

```
\newacronym[first=Machine Virtuelle (VM)]{vm}{VM}{\Gls{glossary:vm}}
\newglossaryentry{glossary:vm}
{
    name={Machine virtuelle},
    description={definiton ... \cite{wiki:vm}.},
    text={machine virtuelle},
}
```

The acronym is used for the first time in the document, appearing in the footnote. But the definition, which is also used for the first time because of the acronym, should also appear in the footnote.
This is not the case here:

[image]

Tag 26, which corresponds to the definition, is present but does not appear in footnote after. Why ? Where is the definition 26 ?

Here is the glossaries-extra configuration I made:

```
 \usepackage[acronym, numberedsection, nonumberlist, automake]{glossaries-extra} % To make a glossary

\glstocfalse
\glsenablehyper
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\setabbreviationstyle{short-postfootnote}

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\printglossdef}{o m}{\footnote{#1: #2}}
\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{general}{0}{page} % Count the number of occurrences per unit, per page of the general group
\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{abbreviation}{0}{page} % Count the number of occurrences per unit, per page of the general group

% If this is the first occurrence of the label
%   then delete the hyperlink to the glossary
% otherwise
\renewcommand{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
    \glsxtrifwasfirstuse%
    {\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}}%
}

% If this is the first occurrence of the label
%   then a footnote is added with the description linked to the tag
% otherwise do nothing
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostlink}{%
    \glsxtrifwasfirstuse%
    {\printglossdef[\glsentryname{\glslabel}]{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}}%
    {}%
}
```

The aim would be for this definition to appear in the footnote at the same level as the acronym or as a sub-footnote.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I explain my problem. Definitions and acronyms appear automatically in the footnotes. In some cases, a definition contains an acronym. Logically, the definition would appear in the footnote, and the acronym would follow.
This is not the case and does not cause a compilation error.

I've attached the link to the template I created and use.
https://github.com/Thorkel-dev/latex.git

**Solution**

Following the comments, here is the solution found in another question : [How to force the numbering of the nested footnote to follow the main footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647575/how-to-force-the-numbering-of-the-nested-footnote-to-follow-the-main-footnote)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hello, I've changed the image I've attached in the hope that it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Do you take a look to this answer ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647575/how-to-force-the-numbering-of-the-nested-footnote-to-follow-the-main-footnote

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly