# Is there a way to add footnotes to footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

Well, the title basically explaines my problem: Adding footnotes inside footnotes doesn't seem to work... Can you help me?

Comment: What about with `bigfoot`? See, e.g., [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36289/8528).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks weird to me ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

A footnote\footnote{gslkdfg djfgh ösdkjfgh öskdj\footnote{foo} g}
\footnotetext{foo}

foo\footnote{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So does this simply work for you?!

Comment: what did you get with my example??

Comment: And what exactly do you do with the `\footnotetext` command?

Comment: `\footnote` in a `\footnote` writes only the `\footnotemark` but not the text. However, it can simply be seen if you comment it out!

Comment: With your example I get the same... But I didn't know that command ^^