# Vertically divided (related) parallel text

Tags: xetex, latex3, parallel, parallel-texts

The question title is I guess a bit off. Actually, what I'm looking for is any package or technique to create a page divided into three parts like this: [image: this] The first part contains some text which is translated literally in the second part and then explained generally in the third part. Basically, all the parts are interconnected; the text in the first part defines the text in the next two parts. Numbers after stanzas in the first part correspond with the numbers after each paragraph of the second part and the third part.

I have looked on `parallel` package, but it can only do this in columns, what I want is clear from the attached picture.

Comment: For one, I don't understand <non-English text> so I don't understand what's the problem. In any case, what's the problem with just type out the text itself (separating the 3 parts with a hrulefill)?

Comment: Let's say a non-English poem stanza is written in the first part, that we are interested to translate and then in the second part English meanings of the individual words in that stanza is written and in the third part the complete English translation of the stanza is given.

Comment: if you want to break pages manually so it's just a tabular or 3 minipages separted by hrules as @user202729 noted but if you want latex to do page breaking i think it's not possible. TeX is not so clever!

Comment: I guess `manyfoot` or `bigfoot` package could do the job; as suggested by @jon at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/footnote-to-a-footnote